# Alterar comportamento padrão chips materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Tem como adicionar uma **tag** com o usuário clicando no enter E no **espaço**?
Pelo padrão do materialize chips ele adiciona só se clicar no enter...

Não encontrei nada sobre, a documentação do materialize é bem ruim.

Por exemplo, se for separando por espaços e clicar no enter fica assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O certo seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$('.chips').chips();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips"></div>
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloquei imagens demonstrando.

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar *chips* com a tecla espaço, basta adicionar o uma função para o método `onkeyup`. Desta forma você poderá detectar quais teclas o usuário pressionou; caso seja o *espaço*, basta usar a função `addChip`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
/* Instancia e cria os campos */
let chips = $('.chips').chips();

/**
 * 1. Captura as instancias do Chip
 * 2. Procura o campo utilizado para escrita
 * 3. Adiciona o evento "keyup" para detecção das teclas
 */
$(chips).find("input").on("keyup", function(e) {

  /* Verifica se o usuário pressionou a tecla "espaço" */
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
  
    /**
     * Captura a instância do "chip"
     * Isto permitirá adicionar, deletar ou selecionar as opções
     */
    let instance = M.Chips.getInstance($(this).parent());
    
    /* Adiciona o "chip" no campo */
    instance.addChip({
      tag: this.value
    })
    
    /* Limpa o campo de texto */
    this.value = ""
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips"></div>
```

Comment: estou usando a versão 0.100.2 do materialize, pq dessa maneira deu esse erro no console "M is not defined" será que é por causa da versão?